# python to android convertion with Kivy

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

I have a Python3 desktop application which I want to convert to an android apk. I saw that Kivy module exists and might be able to pull this off, but I am concerned about it's ability to make the apk work just like the python code. I use many different modules like PIL, opencv, pyserial, threading, watchdog, file_read_backwards etc).

Is this possible or I am asking for too much? And if it is, how can I change/handle for which android version it will the apk be?

Answer (score 0):

- threading is in the stdlib, so you have it
- file_read_backwards is pure python and doesn't seem to require anything (as per setup.py) although the requirements_dev.txt lists a lot more things, so i'm not sure
- PIL has a recipe ([https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/pil/**init**.py](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/pil/__init__.py)), and there is also now a Pillow recipe, which is probably better to use ([https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/Pillow/**init**.py](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/Pillow/__init__.py)) so that seems fine
- pyserial is pure python, and i think i remember people having success with serial over usb on android, though i didn't try myself, it might require a device able to be an usb host and not just client, but i don't know much about that.
- opencv has a recipe, it might be a more touchy one, as it hasn't been touched in years (aside from some cosmetic fixes), and i think i've seen people having issues with it, but i'd say it's worth a shot.

I'd say, it's certainly worth a shot, before converting any of your code, try just building a hello world application with kivy for android, then redo the build but adding your dependencies to the requirements one by one, and see if you can solve it or find help when it doesn't, if all go well, then look into porting your code, which is the part where the success will certainly depend more on you than on what kivy/python-for-android can do.